# Ember.js handling jQuery location changes

Tags: ember.js

Quick question.
I found handling site navigation (not the routing aprt, just a simple nav bar) with ember.js a little complex.
So I thought I will just code this aprt with jQuery, push history into location url and hope that Ember.js will detect this change and the router take action.

Scenario :

1) ember.js will use a DIV for rootElement and the navbar is declared in the body.

```
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul><li><a>Item1</a></li></ul>
  </div> 
  <div id="rootEmberApp"></div>
</body>
```

2) then a jQuery script will be bound to the links (item1) of the nav div and push changes to the URL but preventing default action without stopping the propgation (I didn't want to reload all the scripts). Something like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation a").click(function(event){
    App.router.location.setURL('/ember/listItems');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

3) I was hoping that Ember.js will fire at this time and take action.

I didn't succeed.
Is it silly ? Any idea how to do that ?

Thanks a lot.

**Update 1 :** thanks for the answer. Yes you're right. I was just not fully pleased with the solutions I tried or found about a nav bar. I will look again the todoMVC example and its use of the CollectionView. From a beginner point of view, the CollectionView seems a good way to describe (declare) the View and at the same times it's not easy to read (it's easier when the view is written with pure html and the js is bound to it ala jQuery).
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably not be a satisfactory answer, but... this is not the Ember Way. A core concept of Ember routing is that once the app loads, the source of truth is in Javascript. As you move through an Ember app, the router transitions from state to state and the URL is updated as a side effect. You're trying to turn that on it's head. It's not impossible -- you can definitely get what you're trying to do to work. However, I wanted you to know that it goes against the intention the designers had in mind.